# how to escape from the shell if the selenium is already running?

Tags: php, linux, shell, selenium, terminal

how to escape the terminal if the selenium is already running?, because if I do "CTRL + C" , it will stop the selenium. if I will close the terminal, it will stop the selenium.. so, is there a way to escape the shell and let the selenium run continuously ?

```
php -f seleniumstartstop.php start selenium
```

that's my way of calling the shell script

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your very interesting question. I found out 2 articles to run Selenium Hub/Node as windows service

http://minds.coremedia.com/2013/05/22/selenium-server-as-windows-service-via-nssm/
http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2012/11/selenium-hub-and-node-as-windows-service.html

I've not tried them yet. Good luck